# Regex matching + symbol in url when whitespace is specified. Why?

Tags: php, regex, php-7

I have created a function that makes use of PHP FILTER_VALIDATE_REGEXP.

Moreover the main focus is really on the Regular Expression match.

The regex below is created to match the following patterns:

**2019-07-09** or **2019-07-09+15:30:05**

**Question 1**: Why does $REGEXP_1 returns **true for a plus & a whitespace** when I clearly use a whitespace?

index.php/reports/?from=2019-07-09+15:30:05

TRUE

index.php/reports/?from=2019-07-09 15:30:05

TRUE

```
// ACTIVE REGEX
$REGEXP_1 = '/^([0-9]{4})-([0-1][0-9])-([0-3][0-9])(?:(\s)([0-2][0-9]):([0-5][0-9]):([0-5][0-9]))?$/';

// PREPARE FILTER - STRING
$FILTER_VALIDATE_REGEXP_STRING =  [ 
                                    'filter'  => FILTER_VALIDATE_REGEXP, 
                                    'options' => [ 'regexp' => $REGEXP ] 
                                  ];
```

.

**2019-07-09** or **2019-07-09+15:30:05**

**Question 2**: Why does $REGEXP_2 returns **false for a plus & a whitespace** when I clearly use a plus?

index.php/reports/?from=2019-07-09+15:30:05

FALSE

index.php/reports/?from=2019-07-09 15:30:05

FALSE

```
// ACTIVE REGEX
$REGEXP_2 = '/^([0-9]{4})-([0-1][0-9])-([0-3][0-9])(?:(\+)([0-2][0-9]):([0-5][0-9]):([0-5][0-9]))?$/';

// PREPARE FILTER - STRING
$FILTER_VALIDATE_REGEXP_STRING =  [ 
                                    'filter'  => FILTER_VALIDATE_REGEXP, 
                                    'options' => [ 'regexp' => $REGEXP ] 
                                  ];
```

Comment: The `+` is being url-decoded to a space by PHP

Comment: Is it safe to always assume PHP will do this? Is it a standard? Although... I guess if I use whitespace then it kills two birds with one stone.

Comment: See the Warning on the [urldecode()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.urldecode.php) page

Comment: Cool. So do you think it's best to always use `urldecode()`  prior to passing the parameter to the filter? This would affect how the regex is built.

Comment: Huh?  I suggest you re-read what it says.

Comment: Are you trying to pass the `+` or is that the encoded space? If you want a `+` use `%2B`

Comment: I thought `+` looks clean. Way more clean. Passing the plus sign in the url.

Comment: Whats the theory behind the BOS/EOS ^$ in the regex ?